# acf и wp_insert_post - создание формы размещения материалов

Tags: php, массивы, wordpress

Использую плагин для WordPress - http://www.advancedcustomfields.com

Каким образом возможно организовать форму размещения новых материалов на определённой странице?

Сама задача просматривается явно: создание формы и передача данных.

С первый этапом задачи не возникает трудностей, вся трудность во втором.

Массив для передачи данных от отдельной страницы может быть выполнен по виду:

```
$post_data = array(
'post_title'    => wp_strip_all_tags( $_POST['titlee'] ),
'post_content'  => $_POST['content'],
'post_status'   => 'publish',
'post_author'   => $user_id,
'tags_input'    => $_GET['tag'],
'post_category' => '1'
);
```

Собственно, здесь и возникает вопрос. Какие данные требуются включить в массив, чтобы передать их в материал, в поля плагина acf.

Стандартные данные передать не составляет труда - заголовок, текст материала и прочее. Но вот как поступить с плагином? Возможно, что следует смотреть в сторону "field_groups" - только не до конца определился, каким образом оформить массив для передачи данных.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
update_field($field_key, $value, $post_id);
```

Все подробно, с примерами, рассказано в [источнике](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/update_field/).

Если вкратце:

`$field_key` — ключ поля, не `name`!, если вы хотите НОВЫЙ пост. Для обновления существующего может использоваться и `name`.

`$value` — значение, которое нужно сохранить. Как обычный текст, так и массив, для полей типа `repeater` или `flexible`.

`$post_id` — `ID` созданного поста, которое мы получаем в ответ на `wp_insert_post`. На самом деле в роли `post_id` может выступать и категория и юзер и что угодно, если необходимо.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Очень помогли)